# vim leaving -z binary files after editing

Tags: vim

I've noticed a bunch of "-z" files in directories where I'm editing text files with vim.  At first I thought something strange was going on, but even on brand new CentOS 6.5 servers it's leaving them in directories where i'm editing files.  It appears to create them after I write/quit with shift-zz.

```
root@server [/home/user/public_html]# file ./-z 
./-z: 8086 relocatable (Microsoft)
```

It's real annoying - i'm sure I can create a .vimrc to stop it, but we have way too many servers to implement that.

Comment: Do you have any vim configuration? Does this happen with `vim -u NONE`. This doesn't sound like something vim would do normally.

Comment: It's using the default /etc/vimrc on a fresh centos 6.5 installation.  Yes, it will create it with vim -u NONE also.